# Push notification when user posts/comments in .NET win 8 metro app with PARSE.com

Tags: .net, windows-store-apps, parse-platform

In my app a user posts a question and other users answers the post that time I need to send a push notification to the former user,then this thing happens over again and again as long as the users comment on the same post, same like facebook notifications.How do I do it?. If I create channels for each posts then it will be like 10,000 posts will create 10,000 channels etc so i think that is not an good idea. So any one knew how to achieve it?

Comment: The best way to do it is probably with a mobile service. Keep a table of your users and which users are subscribed to a given thread, then when that threat is updated use the notification system to push one out.

Comment: Well can you elaborate your idea under PARSE.com service

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with Parse.com. It's quite easy to do with Azure though, and should not cost very much either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Logan Wright for his answer in Parse.com.[Check the answer here](https://parse.com/questions/push-notification-when-user-postscomments-in-net-win-8-metro-app).Push can be send to the owner of the posts when he receives a comment.